# VS 2010 Beta 2, cannot add reference to System.Web.Routing from class library

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have a class library project, targeting the .NET Framework 4.0.

I want to have ASP.NET MVC specific extensions here, that I can use in other projects by just adding a reference to the class library.

I have some Routing specific extension methods to accommodate localization in URLs, so I need to add a reference to the System.Web.Routing assembly.

In Visual Studio 2010 beta 2, doing so adds a reference to v4.0 of that assembly - which is empty. I've tried to copy the 3.5 one from the frameworks folder, but that doesn't make a difference.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a workaround for this.

You just have to add reference to System.Web as well.